# Как вывести в textView NSString в котором присутствуют тэги html чтобы они учитывались? Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Есть строка: @"показать подсчеты студентов,
сдающих экзамены";
Как показать эту строку в UITextView или еще в чем, чтобы показывалось форматирование в соответствии с встречающимися html-тэгами?

Comment: Какая версия ios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ из английского so. Ios 7+.

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<h1>Header</h1><h2>Subheader</h2><p>Some <em>text</em></p><img src='http://blogs.babble.com/famecrawler/files/2010/11/mickey_mouse-1097.jpg' width=70 height=100 />";
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
          initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
               options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
    documentAttributes: nil
                 error: nil
];
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Следует заметить, что эта функция довольно медленная, с чем я столкнулся и сам (и не только я http://www.robpeck.com/2015/04/nshtmltextdocumenttype-is-slow/#.WePWsYZpF60). Как вариант использовать предложенную по ссылке библиотеку `DTCoreText`.